# How to use the filter in combox in Ext when we using a tpl

Tags: extjs

According to the Ext API, we could set typeAhead:true to use the filter. However when I use the tpl, the filter cannot work any more. Could anyone help me to solve this out. Thank you very much.

```
    var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data : [
        {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
        {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
        {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
    ]
});



Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    queryMode: 'local',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    triggerAction:'all',
    // Template for the dropdown menu.
    // Note the use of "x-boundlist-item" class,
    // this is required to make the items selectable.
    tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<div class="x-boundlist-item">{abbr} - {name}</div>',
        '</tpl>'
    ),
    typeAhead:true,
        // template for the content inside text field
    displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '{abbr} - {name}',
        '</tpl>'
    )

});
```

Answer (score 0):

for filters I believe you can add `features: [filters]` in ComboBox and define

```
var filters = {
        ftype: 'filters',
        // encode and local configuration options defined previously for easier reuse
        encode: encode, // json encode the filter query
        local: local,   // defaults to false (remote filtering)

        // Filters are most naturally placed in the column definition, but can also be
        // added here.
        filters: [{
            type: 'boolean',
            dataIndex: 'visible'
        }]
    };
```

this should do